# How to create a high dimensional Gaussian that isn't "spiky"?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian

When sampling from a high dimensional Gaussian distribution the results are similar to sampling from a uniform distribution on a unit sphere. Upon searching, I was able to find this mentioned in [1].

This phenomenon already begins in 3D, see [2].

My objective is to construct a distribution in high dimensions such that the property of Gaussians in 1D and 2D holds, mainly that when given a random sample from such a desired distribution, the best guess as to the mean of that distribution is that given sample. And so that there would be a "falloff" from the mean.

How can this be achieved? Can it be done?

[1] https://www.inference.vc/high-dimensional-gaussian-distributions-are-soap-bubble/

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Stein%27s_example

Edit: After some more keyword googling, I was able to find this very recent Twitter thread which further expands on the problem: https://twitter.com/johncarlosbaez/status/1298274201682325509

Comment: Do you have a particular definition of "best guess for the mean of that distribution" in mind?

Comment: @angryavian Perhaps another way of saying that is that the density of the distribution is greatest at the mean, such that when given a sample and nothing else to go on, the best guess you can make is that sample because it is probably close to the mean. It surprisingly does not hold for Gaussians in 3D and up. See [2].

Comment: Unfortunately that particular notion will not work, since the mode of a Gaussian distribution is also its mean. (Your complaint about the Gaussian distribution is that the probability of being near a particular sphere is more than the probability near the mean; this is still possible despite the peak of the density being at the mean.)

Comment: @angryavian Is it possible to adjust the Gaussian distribution such that the probability of being near the mean is greater than near a sphere, that is ultimately my objective. The result will of course no longer be a Gaussian but that doesn't matter. Also I am not sure how it's possible, wouldn't the peak of density then be near the sphere?